# how do I enable pdo extension in my hosting provider

Tags: php, sqlite, hosting, pdo

1) My whole application is built on PDO with sqlite

My Problem:
The hosting provider has PDO --disabled

- I want to know how I can get PDO extensions to work on my hosting provider. The hosting provider just doesn't seem to respond to my queries. So is there any way i can do this remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what functionality your hosting provider supports and how willing you are to switch.

Ideally, you'll want to switch since any webhost that doesn't offer PDO is also probably making nasty mistakes elsewhere too. (PDO is *the* recommended way to use parameterized SQL with PHP to prevent SQL injection attacks)

If you don't want to switch, the simplest solution is probably to follow PEAR's guide to [setting up a local PEAR install](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) and then to run `pear install pdo`.

A more technically correct but more involved solution, if your host allows custom HTTP daemon (Apache) setups is to build your own mod_php in your homedir with PDO enabled and use that. (Using the PDO included with PHP is, as far as I know, the recommended solution for versions that bundle it)

Another option you could try if you can't set up a custom Apache instance is to build a custom PHP but then [use .htaccess to run it via FastCGI](http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html).

I can't think of any options other than that.

Comment: have u tried this. i think i will maybe its a easier solution though i dont know.

Comment: I haven't personally tried it since even the craziest of my hosting providers have been sane enough to offer PDO, but I'd be wary of a project that doesn't seem to even have a proper website for its SourceForge profile to link to... especially when the code will be responsible for ensuring that parameterized SQL is either done with the real APIs or securely faked.

Comment: cant seem to connect to Putty. generated the required .ppk file and loaded it in Connection=>SSH=>Auth=>Private key file for authentication

Comment: I have no experience whatsoever with PuTTY beyond knowing what it is (pure Linux/Unix user here) and I'm not entirely sure what relevance it has to this specific question either.

Comment: sorry. i guess ill post it as a new question. thank u for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is shared hosting, then your web host must allow such functionality. Contact them and explain your needs. If they can't find a way to meet them or your queries continue to go unanswered, switch hosts. There's a gazillion of them.